# DataIntegrityViolationException: Data truncation regarding PreparedStatementCallback

Tags: java, sql, database

I've an issue regarding a PreparedStatementCallback which is showen as the following:

```
 Error! Conflict [#409]: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [EXEC de_table ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?]; Data truncation; nested exception is java.sql.DataTruncation: Data truncation
```

Context:

I have a section which is used to produce tables with values from my application, until recently I found there is no problem except for one of the 4 databases I was testing. The issue is that I can't see why this would be the case as I've tested it on a few other dbs and this page is working as expected. Therefore I'm assuming the code is fine, but the data isn't. I've carried out the same procedure to populate the table, but alas the error still is there.

My request URL consists of the following:

```
accessInd: Any
client: %
endDate: 2020-02-15 23:59:59
entDate: 2020-01-30 11:32:49
entitlementSetMode: 1
entitlementType: Historical
groupItem: %
groupType: 15
service: %
site: %
siteName: %
startDate: 2020-01-30 00:00:00
subservice: %
type: %
userLogin: %
```

Any the values that need to be passed into the prepared statement are the following:

```
                        exampleTable.getSite(),
                        exampleTable.getGroupType(),
                        exampleTable.getGroupItem(),
                        exampleTable.getService(),
                        exampleTable.getType(),
                        exampleTable.getSubservice(),
                        exampleTable.getEndDate(),
                        exampleTable.getMaxRowCount()
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working or any help? Futhermore the % if anyone is wondering is just used for requesting everything related to that value. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your dbs' fields type/size support the data length you are trying to put into it.

Maybe there is a slight schema difference between the three DBs that work and the one that doesn't.

Let's say `yourdb.exampleTable.site` field is a `VARCHAR(10)` and `exampleTable.getSite()` is `"my-site-name-is-more-than-10-chars-long"`, that would cause this `java.sql.DataTruncation` exception to be thrown.